# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, html, django

im trying to create a django page for update a dta inside database, i made this before in other projects and aways worked, but in my project it returns this error: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update/(?P[0-9]+)$']

i reviewed my code a thousand times and i can't see nothing wrong, even if comparing with the other projects.

Obs.: please ignore the css part of my template, i'm not used to write the css inside the html, but as it's just a test i don't create a external file.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
import tables1.views as vw

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name = 'admin'),
    path('mytables/', vw.mytables, name = 'mytables'),
    path('',vw.home),
    path('table/<int:pk>',vw.table, name = 'tableurl'),
    path('newtable/',vw.newtable,name = 'newtable'),
    path('update/<int:pk>',vw.update,name = 'update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>',vw.delete,name = 'delete'),
    path('new/',vw.new, name = 'newurl')
]
```

models.py:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    idd = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tables'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Transacao(models.Model):
    # Forein key defined here
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    obs = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    tableid = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Transacoes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.desc
```

views.py:

```
from .models import Table
from .models import Transacao
from .forms import TableForm
from .forms import TransacaoForm

def home(request):
    now = {}

    return render(request,'tables1/home.html',now)

def mytables(request):
    data = {}
    data['tables'] = Table.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'tables1/mytables.html', data)

def update(request,pk):
    transacao = Transacao.objects.get(pk = pk)
    form = TransacaoForm(request.POST or None, instance=transacao)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return render(request,'tables1/new.html',{'form':form})

def new(request):
    form = TransacaoForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return render(request,'contas/form.html',{'form':form})

def delete(request,pk):
    transacao = Transacao.objects.get(pk = pk)
    transacao.delete()
    return redirect('lists')


def table(request,pk):
    form = TransacaoForm(request.POST or None)
    data = Table.objects.get(idd = pk)
    lists = Transacao.objects.filter(tableid = pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            formdesc = form.cleaned_data['desc']
            formvalue = form.cleaned_data['value']
            transaction_instance = Transacao.objects.create(desc = formdesc,value = formvalue,tableid = pk)

    return render(request,'tables1/table.html',{'data':data, 'form':form, 'lists':lists})

def newtable(request):
    form = TableForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('mytables')
    return render(request,'tables1/newtable.html',{'form':form})
```

table.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;

}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  bottom: 0;
  right-margin: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
.form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* When the inputs get focus, do something */
.form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/login button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Add some hover effects to buttons */
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>{{data}}</h1>

<table id = tabela>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Data e Hora</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            
        </tr>
        {% for list in lists %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{list.desc}}</td><td>{{list.date}}</td>
            <td>{{list.value}}</td><td>{{list.categ}}</td>
            <td><form action="{% url 'update' transacao.id %}">
            <button type="submit"><b>Editar</b></button>
            </form></td>
            <td><form action="{% url 'delete' transacao.id %}">
            <button type="submit"><b>Excluir</b></button>
            </form></td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
</table>

<button class="open-button" onclick="{% url newurl %}">Nova Transação</button>

  <form method="post" class="form-container">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="location.reload()">Login</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`transacao` is not a variable in your template, you use `list` as a variable for a `Transacao` object, therefore you should use `{% url 'update' list.id %}` and `{% url 'delete' list.id %}`:

```
{% for list in lists %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ list.desc }}</td><td>{{ list.date }}</td>
    <td>{{ list.value }}</td><td>{{ list.categ }}</td>
    <td><form action="{% url 'update' list.id %}">
    <button type="submit"><b>Editar</b></button>
    </form></td>
    <td><form action="{% url 'delete' list.id %}">
    <button type="submit"><b>Excluir</b></button>
    </form></td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

That being said, since your `lists` is not a collection of lists - it is a `QuerySet` of `Transacao`s - it might be better to rename `lists` to `transacaos` and use `transacao` as "enumerator".

Comment: I have a different issue, what other occasions can this happen?

Comment: @DerekPK: can you ask a *new* question and share the necessary details of that issue?